# SQL Grouping with Multiple Column Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like below. GiverID and TakerID are both foreign keys to another table, say Person Table. GiverID and TakerID won't be same within a row.

```
ID  GiverPersonID  TakerPersonID  Amount
 1              1              3     100
 2              2              1     200
 3              2              3     400
 4              3              2     800
```

The first row for that table means that Person with ID 1 gives 100 to Person with ID 3.

I need a query to get the result like below

```
PersonID     TotalAmount
       1             100
       2             200
       3            -300
```

Basically, computing the final amount of each person.
For person with ID 1, he gives 100 to person with ID 3, but take 200 from person with ID 2, so his final amount is 200 - 100, which is 100.

I've reading about pivoting, but I think pivoting is not the correct step.

What is the efficient SQL to calculate that result?

Comment: your question is too much unclear

Comment: Does that wanted result really match the sample table data? Describe how you calculate each TotalAmount value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select user_id, sum(amount) from 
(
  select TakerPersonID as user_id, sum(amount) as amount
  from stack56355221
  group by 1
  union all
  select GiverPersonID, sum(-amount)
  from stack56355221
  group by 1
) as t1
group by 1
```

Output:

```
1 100 
2 200 
3 -300
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN A.GiverPersonID IS NULL THEN B.TakerPersonId 
    ELSE A.GiverPersonID
END PersonID, 
B.Take - A.Give TotalAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT GiverPersonID, SUM(Amount)  Give
    FROM your_tabel A
    GROUP BY GiverPersonID
)A
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT TakerPersonId, SUM(Amount)  Take
    FROM your_tabel A
    GROUP BY TakerPersonId
) B
ON A.TakerPersonId= B.TakerPersonId
```

Output is-

```
PersonID    TotalAmount
1           100
2           200
3           -300
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted *all* people -- not just those who are in the table -- then you can try:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(case when p.PersonId = t.GiverPersonID then t.amount else - t.amount end)
        from t
        where p.PersonId in (t.GiverPersonID, t.takerPersonID)
       ) as net_amount
from persons;
```